# Removing Unwanted Data in Juypter Notebook

Tags: python, plot, facet-grid

i was trying to plot a graph and after adding in the code to adjust the x axis label. There are tons of data shown despite me not calling up for them. Is there any way I can either improve my code to remove these set of data? (To be more specific: the whole column that appears as "None")

Codes as below:

```
DataFrame:
q3 = c.execute('''
SELECT Month AS Month, 
   Year AS Year, 
   COUNT(*) AS TotalFlights,
   Dest AS Destination
FROM ontime
WHERE ontime.Cancelled = 0 AND
  Destination = 'ABE' OR Destination = 'CSG' OR Destination = 'HLN' OR Destination = 'LAW' 
GROUP BY Dest, Month, Year
ORDER BY Dest ASC, Year ASC, Month ASC
''').fetchall()
q3 = pd.DataFrame (q3, columns = 
['Month','Year','TotalFlights','Destination'])
pd.DataFrame(q3)
```

[image]

```
Combining Month and Year:
q3["Month"] = q3["Month"].astype(str)
q3["Year"] = q3["Year"].astype(str)
q3['Month_Year'] = q3["Month"] + '/' + q3["Year"]


Plotting of Graph:
>>> g = sns.FacetGrid(data=q3, col="Destination", col_wrap=2, height=6)
>>> g = g.map(plt.plot, "Month_Year", "TotalFlights", marker=".")
>>> [plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45) for ax in g.axes.flat]
```

Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: It's not easy to help without the code and data to reproduce your problem,

Comment: @David, sorry for the earlier mistake, I have edited my post. Hope that it becomes clearer :) thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure, but you could try this : `dummy=[plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45) for ax in g.axes.flat]`

Comment: @David, Hi David, i tried your suggestion and it work, could you kindly put the latest comment as a answer so I can put a tick to it? By the way, what is this dummy and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`[plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45) for ax in g.axes.flat]`

by

`dummy=[plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45) for ax in g.axes.flat]`

In Jupyter or in python prompt. The first one will display the list. So the output that you see. I added the variable `dummy` to disable this behavior. Since the variable is not useful it can be have any name.